# How to show that $r_1, r_2,.., r_k$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $R$ is a matrix in echelon form , then a basis  for $\mathcal{R}(R)$ consists of the non zero rows  of $R$

**My attempt**  : For basis we must show the span and linearly independent properties

let $r_1,r_2 ,..., r_k$ be the non zero rows of $R$ starting from the $1$st row to the  $k-$th row

now we will prove  that $\mathcal{R}(A)= \operatorname{span}  \{ r_1,r_2,....., r_k\}$

for any vector  $v \in \mathcal{R}(A)$, we can write

$ v= c_1r_1 +....+c_kr_k +c_{k+1}0 +......+c_m0= c_1r_1 +....+c_kr_k$

so $v \in \operatorname{span}\{r_1,r_2,........,r_k\}$

Therefore $\mathcal{R}(R) \le\operatorname{span} \{r_1,....,r_k\}$

now trivially we also have $\operatorname{span}\{r_1,....,r_k\} \le  \operatorname{span}\{r_1,r_2,...,r_k,0,0,...,0\} =\mathcal{R}(R)$

This implies  that $\operatorname{span}\{r_1,....,r_k\}=\mathcal{R}(R)$

**My doubts** : How to show that  $r_1, r_2,.., r_k$ are linearly independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**linear independence** By echelon form, you have ordered the rows by the number of zeros on the left. This number of zeros is **strictly** increasing. Take they order from the maximum number of zeros to the minimum (so in your row-echelon matrix you go from the lowest one up to the first row).

Let say you have $r_1,\dots, r_m$ non-zero rows. Now $r_1\neq 0$ so it is lineary independ. Now you add $r_2$, this can't by scalar multiple of $r_2$ because it have non-zero on the position where the $r_1$ has zero.

Now you have proved that $r_1,\dots r_k$ are independ. $r_{k+1}$ has non-zero on the position where all $r_1,\dots r_k$ have zero so it cant be spanned by them.